# Is "read back through the logs" a valid use of the phrasal verb?

Tags: particle-shift

Can "back" split the phrasal verb like this to emphasize that one is going through the logs in reverse chronological order? In general, is splitting phrasal verbs a good idea?

Comment: Why not "backwards"?

Comment: Back is what technical people say to describe that kind of research. Works fine. "I read back through your journal writings, all beautiful."  Works there nicely, too. It's not backwards, more like back in terms of time stamps.

Comment: This shows the inadequacy of the broad-brush 'phrasal verb' analysis. I'd consider 'read back through' to be unitary here, classifying _read back through_ as a transitive multi-word verb with the simplex synonym _re-examine[d]_.

Comment: I would understand "read back through the logs" to means "go back through the logs". That is to say, to go back and read through the logs again. Ricky's suggestion is good: "read backwards through the logs". I'm not sure _read through_ is a phrasal verb, by the way.